# Get text from text box and display it in a paragraph

Tags: javascript, html

If we have a table which contains name, surname and a button(Submit)

for example :

```
   <html>
   <body>
      <table> 

          <tr>
             <td> 
                <label>First name: </label>
             </td>
             <td> 
                <input type="text" id="name" name="firstname" required  />
             </td>
             <td> 
               <label>Last name: </label>
             </td>
             <td> 
               <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" required  />
             </td>

             <td> 
                <button type="submit" onclick="funct()">Submit</button>
             </td>
          </tr>

       </table> 

      <p id="mane1"> </p>

    </body>
  </html>
```

and when we click submit we want do display the text that we get from text boxes in a new paragraph:

Your name is : RandomName

Your surname is : RandomSurname

How can we do this?

I tried this :

```
function funct(){

 var name=document.getElementById("name").value;
 if (name!=""){
    document.getElementById("name1").innerHTML="Your Name Is:"+ name;
}
}
```

The problem is that if I click "Submit" it doesn't show anything.

I tried to find something useful over the internet , but all the examples that I used didn't do anything.

I will appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After changing the p id to "name1", the code you posted works fine. Are you sure the problem isn't somewhere else in your code?

I noticed that your button is a submit type. Is it in a form? If it is, then your browser might be submitting the form and reloading the page so fast you don't see the javascript actually working. You can change the button type to "button" to prevent the form from submitting.

Answer (score 0):

Is the "name1" vs. "mane1" a typo?  If that is a typo, and in the code you have it right, then try using .innerText or putting html tags in your .innerHtml string.

```
function funct(){

   var name=document.getElementById("name").value;
   if (name!=""){
      // document.getElementById("name1").innerHTML="Your Name Is:"+ name;
      document.getElementById("mane1").innerHTML="<p>Your Name Is:"+ name + "</p>";
   }
}
```

EDIT:  Further consideration

Is your script

```
function funct(){

   var name=document.getElementById("name").value;
   if (name!=""){
      document.getElementById("mane1").innerHTML="<p>Your Name Is:"+ name + "</p>";
   }
}
```

After your call to the script.  Going from top to bottom on the page?

```
<button type="submit" onclick="funct()">Submit</button>
```

If not, then it may be an issue with the dom not knowing what funct() is yet.  In other words, make sure your script is at the bottom, or activated by something higher on the page content than where you are trying to use it.

Comment: My mistake here. 
My real code is more than 300 rows , and  used this short code as an example :)

Comment: Yes . I really appreciate your help :) Thank you